# Adjusting all line to Left side of the file in gvim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm new to the `vim` editor.

How can I adjust all lines to the left? I have many lines which are indented and I want to arrange them so they *all* abut the left side of the file (no spacing at the start of the lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all line in visual mode and then type **:left** . Hope this helped.

***keerthan***

Comment: thanks....................

Answer (score 1):

The simple key sequence `:%left` will do the trick, it basically applies the `left` command to all lines in the file.